# Getting Boarding Pass from inside Transit area in Dubai Terminal 1

Tags: transit, tickets, dubai, dxb, airport-terminals

Is there any PIA counter for boarding pass inside Transit Area in Dubai airport Terminal 1? I am a Pakistani National and travelling from Sweden to Dubai Terminal 1 and have separate booking for my onward journey for Flight PK 222 to Multan. 
I don't have any checked baggage and I only need boarding pass for flight PK 222 from inside Transit area at Terminal 1, Is it possible to get boarding pass while in Transit area without going through immigration?

OR, Is it possible to get PIA flight PK 222 boarding pass from any other Service Desk inside Transit Area in terminal 1 in Dubai?

Please advise,

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you [check in online](https://www.piac.com.pk/#web-checkin)? Either way you should be able to get your boarding pass at the transit desks.

Comment: No, its not possible to check in online for PIA.